# How to perform an action depending on various checkbox status?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I want to call a JavaScript function depending on the check boxes status.

For example if only checkbox 1 is active, I want to call the function `genPDF()`

If all checkboxes are active I want to invoke the function `gen4PDF()` once I press the generate report button, etc.

As far as I know I can do something like that: (and it works)
`<a href="javascript:genPDF()"> DOWNLOAD PDF </a>`

But I want a more 'smart' link/button. How can I do it?

My code skeleton:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>System Overview Report</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        function genPDF(){

        }

        function gen2PDF(){

        }

        function gen3PDF(){

        }

        function gen4PDF(){

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="checkbox" name="basic">I want basic report<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="network">I want network report<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="suggestions">I want suggestions report<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="complete">I want a complete report

    <a href="javascript:genPDF()"> GENERATE PDF REPORT </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want to change the button text as well?

Comment: @lipp Nope, the button will be used only for calling a javascript function, for example: `"javascript:genPDF()"`

Comment: You will need more function since you can have combination of checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, of course, it's just an example! Once I figure out how to do it I'll create the necessary functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code for two cases first checkbox and all checkboxes:

```js
function genPDF() {
  console.log('genPDF');
}

function gen2PDF() {
  console.log('gen2PDF');
}

function gen3PDF() {
  console.log('gen3PDF');
}

function gen4PDF() {
  console.log('gen4PDF');
}
function generate() {
  var basic = document.querySelector('[name="basic"]').checked;
  var network = document.querySelector('[name="network"]').checked;
  var suggestions = document.querySelector('[name="suggestions"]').checked;
  var complete = document.querySelector('[name="complete"]').checked;
  if (basic && !network && !suggestions && !complete) {
    genPDF();
  } else if (basic && network && suggestions && complete) {
    gen4PDF();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="basic">I want basic report<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="network">I want network report<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="suggestions">I want suggestions report<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="complete">I want a complete report

<a href="javascript:generate()"> GENERATE PDF REPORT </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var checkBoxes=document.getElementsByClassName('pdf');
for(var i=0; i<4;i++){
    checkBoxes[i].onclick=function(){
        var checkedNum=0;
        for(var j=0; j<4;j++){
            if(checkBoxes[j].checked){
                checkedNum++
            }
        }

        switch (checkedNum){

            case 1:
                genPDF();
                break;
            case 2:
                gen2PDF();
                break;
            case 3:
                gen3PDF();
                break;
            case 4:
                gen4PDF();
                break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ma Yubo, this is not what I'm looking for...thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all checkbox states like this:

```
var options = {}
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
  options[this.name] = this.checked
})
```

You can check against single or multiple options to figure out what to do.

```js
genPDF = function() {
  var options = {}
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    options[this.name] = this.checked
  })
  
  if (options.basic && !options.network) {
    // etc
  } else if () {
    // etc
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

    <input type="checkbox" name="basic">I want basic report<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="network">I want network report<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="suggestions">I want suggestions report<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="complete">I want a complete report

    <a href="javascript:genPDF()"> GENERATE PDF REPORT </a>
</body>
```